# Scroll down tableView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view which received data from a real-time database. These data are added from the bottom of the table view and so on this table view has to scroll down itself to show new data.

I've found a method to do it however I'm not satisfied because the scroll always start from the top of the list. Not very beautiful.

Here is the code of this method :

```
func tableViewScrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {

    let delay = 0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        let numberOfSections = self.clientTable.numberOfSections
        let numberOfRows = self.clientTable.numberOfRowsInSection(numberOfSections-1)

        if numberOfRows > 0 {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: (numberOfSections-1))
            self.clientTable.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: animated)
        }

    })
}`
```

Is there a way to modify this method in order to scroll only from the previous position ?

Comment: Is the problem really here in the scrolling logic? Or are you doing a `reloadData` before you call this? Calling `reloadData` will always scroll to the top. If you can, do `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` for the added rows will keep it from scrolling up to the top.

Comment: Indeed you're right I do a reloadData. I'm trying to reloadRowsAtIndexPaths but for the moment it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually I noticed that even if I remove reloadData, when I insert a row the table view scroll up to the top. Is there any reason to this ?

Comment: It's not the scrolling code in your question. It's something else (perhaps a `reloadData` that's lingering about that you missed). And, btw, it's not `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` (that's for updating existing rows in such a way that it won't scroll to the top like `reloadData` does), but rather `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`, like shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is probably how the rows were inserted into the table. For example, if you add rows to the end using something like this, you get a very smooth UI:

```
@IBAction func didTapAddButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let count = objects.count
    var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()

    // add two rows to my model that `UITableViewDataSource` methods reference;
    // also build array of new `NSIndexPath` references

    for row in count ..< count + 2 {
        objects.append("New row \(row)")
        indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0))
    }

    // now insert and scroll

    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .None)
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPaths.last!, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
}
```

Note, I don't reload the table, but rather call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. And I turned off the animation because I know they're off screen, and I'll then scroll to that row.

[image]

Comment: I don't have same behavior of yours in my table. There is always a kind of scroll top before scroll bottom

Comment: @Bram'in - Perhaps you can update your question with the code that updates the table and then initiates the scroll. I suspect the former, not the latter. We need 'reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).